# How to use "class name1::name2::name3" notation to define class in c++

Tags: c++, class

Could somebody explain me how the following notation of class definition works in c++

class name1::name2::name3
{
...
...
...
}

I know how to define and use class on its own but have no idea about "class name1::name2::name3" notation and how to use it

Many Thanks,

Comment: [This](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace) may help

Comment: why do you think you need it?

Comment: I'm new to c++ and have a code to read which contains following notation

Comment: Ok, got it is a class of namespace::name1::name2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `name1`, `name2` are namespaces while `name3` is the name of the class. Namespaces help you to organize your code. I have never seen `class name1::name2::name3 { ... ... ... }` in the wild, though one case where one could use it when a class is forward declared in a namespace, but defined in a different one, as for example:

```
namespace foo { class bar; }

class foo::bar {};
```

However, this isnt very common and if possible you would define the class inside the same namespace where it is declared, eg

```
 namespace foo { class bar; }
 // then possibly elsewhere
 namespace foo { class bar {}; }
```

After writing this, I realized another possiblity that is perhaps less uncommon than the above. `name1` and `name2` could each be classes, as for example:

```
class name1 {
    class name2 {
        class name3;
    };
};

// now define name3:
class name1::name2::name3 {};
```

Comment: I think in my case name1 is a namespace and name2 and name3 are classes

Comment: @IceDefcon thats possible. `name1::name2` is the scope of `name3` whether this is namespaces or other classes you cannot see from the full name (`name1::name2::name3`) alone